# php conditional preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I found a regex sample and it is usefull for me. Now I need to modify it but I am very bad on regex. I searched google and tried something but I failed.

here is regex I found:

```
            $parsedMessage =
            preg_replace(
                array(
                    '/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/',
                    '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ_]+)/i'),
                array(
                    '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',
                    '$1<a href="/$2">@$2</a>',
                    '$1<a href="/hashtag/$2">#$2</a>'),
                $message);
```

It returns $message with replaced # hashtags, @ mentions and normal links, and now I want to add this one (also found it),

```
    return preg_replace(
    '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i',
    "<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$2\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"480\" height=\"270\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
    $string
);
```

Like you get it, It returns replaced youtube links to embed code. If I use it like this:

```
$parsedMessage =
        preg_replace(
            array('/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i',
                '/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/',
                '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i', '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ_]+)/i'),
            array('<iframe src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$2\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"480\" height=\"270\" allowfullscreen></iframe>',
                '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>',
                '$1<a href="/$2">@$2</a>',
                '$1<a href="/hashtag/$2">#$2</a>'),
            $message);
```

Returns

But it is not what I want. Here is what I need:

If $message includes youtube link, replace link with embed and go on replacing normal links to  tag.Else, just replace normal links to

Thank you for your helps.

Comment: I'd recommend looking in to [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) where you can have a function that can read the matched groups before deciding whether or not to replace the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem. If you need, you may use it :)
[Get it on github gist.](https://gist.github.com/dmrc1143/8e778a522652c12b6cd877cb22555b4e)

Here $message is a text that will be replaced. (#hastags @mentions and http://youtube.com?v=blabla is replaced)

User::where('username', $m[2])->exists()  is part of laravel, you may comment this condition

$parsedMessage3 is replaced text. And note that, only one youtube link is allowed.

```
    function convert_clickable_links($message)
{

    global $youtube_link;
    global $count;

    $parsedMessage1 = preg_replace_callback(
        '/(?i)\b((?:https?:\/\/|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))/',
        function ($m) use($youtube_link,$count)
        {
            $matches=[];

            $match_bool=preg_match
            (
                '/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i',
                $m[0],
                $matches
            );

            if($match_bool)
            {
                global $youtube_link;
                global $count;
                if($count>1)
                {
                    return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[1].'</a>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $youtube_link='<iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/'.$matches[2].'" type="text/html" width="100%" height="270" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
                }
                ++$count;
                return  '';
            }
            else
            {
                return '<a href="'.$m[1].'" target="_blank">'.$m[1].'</a>';
            }
        },
        $message,-1,$count);

    $parsedMessage1=$parsedMessage1.$youtube_link;

    $parsedMessage2= preg_replace_callback(

        '/(^|[^a-z0-9_])@([a-z0-9_]+)/i',
        function ($m) {
            if (User::where('username', $m[2])->exists())
            {
                return $m[1].'<a href="/'.$m[2].'">@'.$m[2].'</a>';
            }
            else
            {
                return ' @'.$m[2];
            }
        },
        $parsedMessage1);

    $parsedMessage3=preg_replace('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9şŞıİçÇöÖüÜĞğ_]+)/i','$1<a href="/hashtag/$2">#$2</a>',$parsedMessage2);


    return $parsedMessage3;

}
```